# Location of celeryd folder on Ubuntu?

Tags: django, ubuntu, django-celery

I'm following instructions to setup **djcelery** in production.

> Download the daemon script :
>   https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/contrib/generic-init.d/celeryd
>
> Put it in /etc/init.d/celeryd

However, I don't have a folder in /etc/init.d/ called **celeryd**.

I'm running Ubuntu, celery works if I run `manage.py celeryd -l info` so its all setup and installed correctly.

Where is the correct folder to add the script on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They meant "put it in `/etc/init.d/` as `celeryd`". Since it's already named `celeryd`, just put it in `/etc/init.d`.